# Как получить переменные из родительского конструктора класса в дочернем конструкторе класса?

Tags: python, ооп

Как можно получить переменные из конструктора родительского класса в конструкторе дочернего класса? Я не хочу повторно передавать аргументы дочернему классу, которые уже передаются родительскому классу, то есть `x, y`.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_new = self.x
        self.y_new = self.x

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.x_new, self.y_new)

x = A(x=10, y=10)
y = B()
y.do_something()

>>> (ожидается вывод): 10, 10
```

Comment: Почитайте о  `super` https://realpython.com/python-super/#an-overview-of-pythons-super-function, и в документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: А почему вдруг у `y.do_something()` ожидается вывод 10, 10 если `y` не имеет никакого отношения к `x` - это два разных объекта? Откуда в `y` вообще будет 10, если оно нигде ему не передавалось? А по теме - вы не можете избежать получения параметров в дочернем классе, ведь вы вынуждены будете их передать как `B(x=10, y=10)`, а потом в `B` вызвать еще явное `super().__init__(x, y)` (в питоне это требуется делать явно и вручную), чтобы параметры добрались до родительского класса.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не понимаете до конца разницы между экземплярами класса и самим классом. Данные **экземпляра** класса `A` есть только **в этом самом экземпляре**. Вы должны их как-то "вручную" передать потомку. Либо нужно хранить эти данные в самом классе `A`, а не в его экземпляре, тогда да, тогда класс-потомок может при желании получить эти данные из класса-предка.